# Hard drive sounds cyclically after a little while

Tags: hard-drive

I have Windows 7. After a little while of inactivity my hard disc sounds cyclically with this sound:
https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B54CGNwoXQw2dDZvU3FQRnFUM28

please, can you tell me why? Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

### The drive is bad.

Backup your important data from it while you still can.